# Combinatorics question regarding solving using multinomial theorem

Tags: combinatorics, multinomial-theorem

Given, there are 30 questions in a multiple choice test. A student gets 1 mark each for an unattempted question, 4 marks for a correctly answered question, and 0 for a wrongly answered one. If the number of questions he does correctly be x and he scores 60, what are the number of possible values of x?

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
\text{Right (4 Marks)}& \text{Wrong (0 Marks)}  & \text{Unattempted (1 Mark)} \\ \hline
\text{15} & 15 & 0\\ \hline
\text{14} &  & 4\\ \hline
\text{13} &  & 8\\ \hline
\text{12} &  & 12\\ \hline
\text{11} &  & 16\\ \hline
\text{10} &  & 20\\ \hline
\end{array}$$
Not filling up the "**Wrong**" column as there may be 1,2,3,...many possibilities for that column and it still wouldn't affect my answer. 
And I stop here as the maximum number of questions possible is 30. From here, I get my answer to be $6$, which is correct.

Now I was wondering if this could be solved using the multinomial theorem....by generating a function as follows:-

$$4\times x_1+0\times x^2 + 1\times x_3 = 60$$
$$4x_1+x_3 = 60$$

Is this the correct way to go about solving this question? If so, how would I find the number of solutions to the above equation??

Comment: This seems like this is far before multinomial theorem should come into play... this sounds like an introductory highschool algebra word problem.  We have a line $4x_1+x_3=60$, and we have a triangular region given by $x_1+x_3\leq 30, 0\leq x_1, 0\leq x_3$ and we ask which and/or how many integer points lie along that line.

Comment: Yes I do see the upper and lower bounds for $x_1$, guess I was just complicating stuff too much